# Can I say "... have us been provided"? :)

Tags: grammaticality

Can I say "this robot have us been provided", without being gramatically incorrect? :)
Or is it only "this robot have been provided".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would say “This robot has been provided” since “robot” is singular.

Comment: Or, "This robot has been provided to us", if you wish to explicitly identify the recipient.

Comment: "We have been provided [with] a robot" would also be correct and idiomatic, "with" being optional.